# SQL Server : add CSV programmable

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following code to insert a CSV file into a temp table:

```
USE [websitehere.com].[dbo]
GO
CREATE TABLE [websitehere.com].[dbo].[tmpTable]
(ID INT,
    Caller_Number VARCHAR(100),
    Caller_Name VARCHAR(100),
    GroupBy VARCHAR(100),
    Campaign_Name VARCHAR(100),
    DateAndTime VARCHAR(100),
    Duration VARCHAR(100),
    Call_Status VARCHAR(100))
GO;

BULK
INSERT tmpTable 
FROM 'C:\Users\namehere\Documents\CallLog.csv' 
WITH
(
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
GO
```

But...

1. It does not seem to add the `tmpTable`. It gives me an error

   > *Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
   >
   >   Incorrect syntax near '.'.*
2. It won't add the insert command saying that

   > *Msg 4834, Level 16, State 4, Line 8
   >
   >   You do not have permission to use the bulk load statement.*

Any help would be great to take care of these 2 errors!

**Update**

[image: db user secutirys]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah found where i needed to grant access to be able to use it!

[image]

```
Right-click on your database table > 
properties > 
select Permissions from the left panel >
click the blue link "View server permissions" >
check "Grant" for "Administer bulk operations" >
Ok > Ok > Done!
```

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
USE [websitehere.com].[dbo]
```

should say

```
USE [websitehere.com]
```

The second error should be fixed by assigning the propper permissions or role memeberships for your user.  You need INSERT and ADMINISTER BULK OPERATIONS permissions. Maybe more, depending on what other options your bulk insert statement might have.

You might want to try this with some test user account:

```
USE master;
GO
CREATE LOGIN bulkuser WITH PASSWORD = 'P@ssw0rd';
GRANT ADMINISTER BULK OPERATIONS to bulkuser;

USE [websitehere.com]
GO
CREATE USER bulkuser FOR LOGIN bulkuser;
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_datareader', 'bulkuser'
GRANT INSERT ON [dbo].[tmpTable] TO bulkuser;
```

Then login as "bulkuser" and try running your BULK INSERT statement.

Comment: I am the admin of the database. How can i check those permissions?

Comment: If you are the admin of the database, why don't you use a sufficiently powerfull account? Anyhow, go to the user-object in the object explorer and look up the permissions of the user on the table and server in question.

Comment: Solved! Thanks for the help, though!